# How to update from "input" actual visible "value" on page using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have problems with setting the view value of some input fields that are filled programatically:

1. when it is empty, script adds "0";
2. if number > 360, script sets to "360".

```html
<p>
    <span style="color: #81a0ff; font-size: 3em; font-weight: bold;">
        &alpha; = {{angle1}}&deg;
    </span>
</p>
<input type="text" id="ang_1" maxlength="3" 
    onfocus = "this.value = parseInt(value) || ''"
    onblur = "this.value = parseInt(value) || '0'" 
    onkeyup="this.value = minmax(this.value, 0, 360) || 0"
    ng-model="angle1"
    ng-init="angle1='0'" >
```

```js
function minmax(value, min, max)
{
    if (parseInt(value)== 0 || parseInt(value)== 00 || parseInt(value)== 000 )
        return 0;
    if(parseInt(value) < min)
        return 0;
    else if(parseInt(value) > max)
        return 360;
    else return value = parseInt(value);
}
```

How can I fix that problem?

Comment: Put your solution to jsfiddle.net

Comment: What is `this.value` in the HTML?  And is `minmax` a global function?

Comment: I believe your issue is that AngularJS doesn't know to update since your minmax is a global function that lives outside of Angular. [Check out this fiddle, I just moved your function into the controller of the input.](https://jsfiddle.net/1dj4zn7b/). The data updates on blur using angular `ngBlur`.

Comment: You could create a custom AngularJS Directive that could handle all of this and on a global level and allow you to pass any min max combo.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you want to achieve. `minmax` is returning `0` or `360`, you should return `value+0` to add `0` when your value is lower than `min`. Also, `parseInt("value")` automatically trims zeroes (see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)). Could you elavorate a bit?

Comment: Problem is in displaying currently visible input value. I'm printing "999", script corrects it to "360", but angular continues to show "999" in h1tag instead of 360 that is dispalyed correctly in input field.

Comment: use input type number

Comment: There is problem with displaying of current visible input-tag value using angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is the solution of my problem:

```
   http://jsfiddle.net/MTfRD/2207/
```

As a result: script corrects the number according to minmax function (last one must be in controller) and angularjs displayes visible value of input field.
Thanks to everyone for help and especially to Asok for tip.
HTML

```
<div ng-app="DispAngleApp"  ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
<p><span class="alfa">&alpha; = {{angle1}}&deg;</span></p>
<input type = "text" 
        id = "ang_1"
        maxlength = "3"
        onfocus = "this.value = parseInt(value) || ''"
        onblur = "this.value = parseInt(value) || '0'"
        ng-change = "minmax(angle1, 0, 360) || 0"
        ng-model = "angle1"
        ng-init = "angle1='0'" ><br>
<p><span class = "beta">&beta; = {{angle2}}&deg;</span></p>
<input type = "text"
        id = "ang_2"
        maxlength = "3"
        onfocus = "this.value = parseInt(value) || ''"
        onblur = "this.value = parseInt(value) || '0'"
        ng-change = "minmax2(angle2, 0, 360) || 0"
        ng-model = "angle2"
        ng-init = "angle2='0'"><br>
```

AngularJS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]); function AppCtrl($scope) {
$scope.minmax = function (value, min, max) {
    if (value == '')
        return $scope.angle1 = 0;
    if (parseInt(value) == 0 || parseInt(value) == 00 || parseInt(value) == 000)
        return $scope.angle1 = 0;
    if (parseInt(value) < min)
        return $scope.angle1 = 0;
    else if (parseInt(value) > max)
        return $scope.angle1 = 360;
    else return $scope.angle1 = parseInt(value);
};
$scope.minmax2 = function (value, min, max) {
    if (value == '')
        return $scope.angle2 = 0;
    if (parseInt(value) == 0 || parseInt(value) == 00 || parseInt(value) == 000)
        return $scope.angle2 = 0;
    if (parseInt(value) < min)
        return $scope.angle2 = 0;
    else if (parseInt(value) > max)
        return $scope.angle2 = 360;
    else return $scope.angle2 = parseInt(value);
};
$scope.change_val = function (value){
    var va = value;
    va = va.replace(/^\[\'|\'\]$/g,'').split("', '");
    $scope.angle1 = va[0];
    $scope.angle2 = va[1];
} } function change_val(el){
var ang_1 = document.getElementById("ang_1");
var ang_2 = document.getElementById("ang_2");
var v = el.value;
v = v.replace(/^\[\'|\'\]$/g,'').split("', '");
ang_1.value = v[0];
ang_2.value = v[1];}
```